# How to capture UIView as UIImage in particular frame?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimage, quartz-2d

Hi i want to covert my `UIView` to `UIImage` in particular frame size kindly help me.

1. I have 'UITableView` which is added as subview of 'UIScrollView' for horizontal scroll, my table view frame size is (0, 0, 12000, 768).
2. I want to convert the current visible are of my `UITableView` as `UIImage` after scrolling.

Example:

if i scrolled my table view horizontally some distance means that current visible are is (150,0,1200,768) that means full device screen.

1. if i use the following code:

   ```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
   [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
   UIImage *backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   ```

   its capturing always the frame size of (0, 0, 1200, 768) only.

so, how can i set the origin of image capturing.

Kindly help me out.... Thanks in advance....

Comment: At what point in the code are you implementing the image context?

Comment: Try using self.window.layer instead of self.layer

Comment: i have table view which size is (12000, 768), i fitted in uiscroll view for horizontal scrolling, now when ever i pinch my table view, i want to capture current visible area as image. Example: is i scrolled my table view horizontal means the current visible frame is (200, 0, device.screen.width, device.screen.height). this area only i have to capture as image. how can i do this #akashg

Answer (score 4):

```
- (UIImage *)rasterizedImageInView:(UIView *)view atRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y);
    [view.layer renderInContext:context];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

This will allow you to capture a `UIImage` from a particular region within a `UIView` as defined by a `CGRect`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect rect = [self.view bounds];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
UIView *viewprint=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
viewprint.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
[viewprint addSubview:tableView];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewprint.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[view.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: [view.layer renderInContext:context]; in this view is viewprint right, and what is tableview, materialAndLaburListTableView #madhuri